# elasticsearch how to find a document with exact word match

Tags: python, database, elasticsearch

I have some data in ES. For example

```
{
result: [{
    id: 1,
    full_text: some dummy text
}, {
    id: 2,
    full_text: i read my book sometimes
}, {
    id: 3,
    full_text: somewhere in time is one of the greatest albums of all time
}]
```

}

I have to create some query that returns all documents with exact match of a word in a full_text field. For example if I want to get all document with a word "some" in a full_text it has to return just first one without fuzzy search and words like "something, somewhere" etc. don't have to be considered.
I tried using match, term, but that don't return exact word match.
I also try to use regexp but can't create correct one. For example this one returns nothing like there are no documents with a word "some" in "full_text"

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "summary_text": {
                "value": "\bsome\b"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know correct query or regexp for this kind of search?

Comment: is result an array inside a document?

Comment: No, just text. This is exact result:
"hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 1.0,
         "hits": [{id, full_text: some dummy text}, {
    id: 2,
    full_text: i read my book sometimes
}]

Comment: match query will work in this case . Can you add the query you have tried and also mapping of index

Comment: According to your answer I've just tried:
{
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "full_text": {
            "query": "define"
          }
        }
      }
    }
to find all documents with word "define" inside. But this query also returns documents with words like "defines", "defined"

Comment: Can you add your mapping , I think stemmer is used in your mapping which is reducing token to roots. Please add mapping to confirm. You will get mapping by GET index-name/_mappings

Comment: Thank you for a tip how to find this mapping) 
The whole mapping is more than 4000 lines long so I'll provide the part that applies to "full_text" and "summary_text" that i need to make search :"mappings": {"agencies": {"full_text": {"type": "text","fields": {"reverse": {"type": "text","analyzer": "reverse"},"trigram": {"type": "text","analyzer": "trigram"}},"copy_to": ["light_stem","shingled"],"analyzer": "english"},"full_text_hash": {"type": "keyword"},"summary_text": {"type": "text","fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword","ignore_above": 256}}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will look at your mapping, "analyzer": "english" is used for field full_text

[English](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) analyzer provides stemming be default i.e it breaks tokens to their word root . The token created for define/defines is defin
so defin, define, defines all three are equivalent.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "agencies": {
      "full_text": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "reverse": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "reverse"
          },
          "trigram": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "trigram"
          }
        },
        "copy_to": [
          "light_stem",
          "shingled"
        ],
        "analyzer": "english"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need to update your mapping and create a sub field of type text without any analyzer.

If you some subfields defined like reverse and copy to light_stem and shingled. Their definition is not present in your mapping so can't test at my end. You can try match queries against these too ex. full_text.reverse:"define"

copy_to is used to copy value of multiple fields to a single place. Your match query will work against these but if any other field(with copy_to) has word define but full_text doesn't have it, still that document will be returned.